# How to create customized swipeable tabs in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create customized swipeable tabs in my android application project as I have provided in the

**picture here**

[image: picture here].

Comment: You can create style and theme for android SlidingTabLayout. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
As I tried.. you can do well..

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

...........................
...........................

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
```

add **PagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.truiton.designsupporttabs;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Reference...

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: App crashes out using the above method @Kush

Comment: Yes i checked the reference. Error when launching "Unfortunately app has stopped"

Comment: see LogCat and  find what is causing the app to crash. share error.. lets see

Answer (score 0):

Since link only answers are not allowed in the SO, adding some kind of steps to do.

**Step 1 :** 
Define three different set of Fragment Classes that will be used for each tabs. [ Android recommends to use fragments instead of Activity ]

**Step 2 :** 
 Define a Pager adapter that will help you to load the above three fragments under each tabs.

**Step 3 :**
In you main activity define the tablayout, and set the above adapter as shown in the tutorial link.

Kindly refer the below tutorial, that is very basic and help you achieve what you needed.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Above link, only guides you to implement the swipe-able views. If you need to implement the exact design like the image you posted needs some work in your styles xml or try with drawable images here.

[One more useful link](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-tab-with-swipe-views-viewpager-fragmentpageradapter-in-android-studio/)

Let me know for queries.

**EDIT**

I'm also refering to the same thing what @kush mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make similar tab layout using pageadapter. Below is the code for the same.

MainActivity code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the viewpager in activity_main.xml
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }
}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

PageAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
// Tab Titles
private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "PLAYLIST", "SONGS", "ALBUMS" };
Context context;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            SongsList fragmenttab1 = new SongsList();
            return fragmenttab1;

        // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            SecondFragment fragmenttab2 = new SecondFragment();
            return fragmenttab2;

        // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            ThirdFragment fragmenttab3 = new ThirdFragment();
            return fragmenttab3;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabtitles[position];
}
}
```

You can create n fragments in your project. Here is the example fragment code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

and its XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/Fragment2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add this RESOURCE values to remove the action bar,title bar in layout in styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
</resources>
```